# Implementing session in SOAP Client

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, soap

I am developing a WP application for which the webservices are implemented in .NET using SOAP client. I have implemented the SOAP client in my WP app using "Add service reference" option.

Now the problem is, there are two different client classes one for the Login functionality and the other for all other queries. Login is working fine and returning me true or false and nothing else. And the other client class is used to make different queries which are all working fine and getting some data from server. After testing I observed that the response is independent of the logged in user( ie server sending same data irrelevant of the logged in user). And hence it is clear that the session is not maintained and the server is sending some anonymous data.

Some one help me on how to maintain the session in the SOAP client.

Note: I cannot ask the web service providers on this. :(

Comment: You can't maintain it as the consumer - the secondary service should be asking for a private key to provide data - clearly you could ask for data from this service and never login. If you wrote the web service then you have other options.

Comment: What are the other options? My doubt is, there might be some option to maintain session and I may be missing it. So I want to know all the possible ways of maintaining the session in a SOAP client.

Comment: There are no other options if you didn't write it, the session has to be maintained server-side. You login, a session is established, a key is returned to you, and that key is used when querying the other services that require a session so you can be authenticated during the service call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I figured out how to maintain cookie based session in Windows phone apps

Thanks to Mike for his guidance.

For all those who are wondering about the different ways of maintaining session in WP app,
there is a class called `CookieContainer` which helps to maintain cookie data for us.

Usage:

First create a global instance of CookieContainer class ( I created in App.xaml.cs)

```
//In App.xaml.cs
CookieContainer cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
```

And then assign it to every request we make to the server from our app.

```
MySoapClient client = new MySoapClient();
client.CookieContainer = (App.Current as App).cookieContainer;
client.LoginAsync("username", "password");
```

Again for any other request in the app

```
MyOtherSoapClient anotherClient = new MyOtherSoapClient();
anotherClient.CookieContainer = (App.Current as App).cookieContainer;
anotherClient.PostDataAsync("somedata");
```

The same rule also applies for normal `WebClient` and `HttpWebRequest` classes also.

Happy Coding :)