# SessionState Collection item disappearing when called from a desktop client

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, iis, soap

I've got a legacy ASP.NET soap web service on my computer. The service has this annotation:

```
 [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
```

on several methods and uses the Session property to save some information:

```
Session[CONSTANT] = some_value;
```

This value is preserved when I call different methods of the web service one after another in a browser (both Chrome and Internet Explorer) but NOT when I call the service methods from a proxy created in Powershell or in Visual Studio.
Do I have to set some parameters on the client to preserve the Session?

On another computer the same service is installed and there the value stored in the Session is NOT preserved between method calls, not even in the browsers. Do I need then to change some parameters in the web server in this case?

In both cases the web service is hosted in IIS.

Comment: ASP.NET session uses cookies. You should make sure cookies are preserved all along the way, in the browsers (most of the time, this should be automatic, as you observed), and in the proxies as well.

Comment: how can I make sure? some hints as of the settings?

Comment: difficult to say w/o some reproducing code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following has done the job for me:

1. adding a legacy web reference instead of service reference.
2. using the `SoapClient.CookieContainer`like in 
   [Implementing session in SOAP Client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11830168/implementing-session-in-soap-client)